# Create shortcut for check-in or check-out

Tags: check-out, check-in, shortcut

Is there an easy way to create a shortcut to check-in or check-out an item of a list (or library)? I see a JS is making this work, but I would get the URL/Command that is created in order to put a shortcut ion the page avoiding user to go to the ribbon and use the icon there.
I can imagine something like 
javascript:displayLayover('siteURL/listname/Forms/something.aspx?ID=itemID&IsDlg=1'
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To check in:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function checkIn_Success(sender, args)
           {
               window.location.reload();
           }
           function checkIn_fail(sender, args)
           {
             alert('Something went wrong');
           }
           function checkIn()
           {
               var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
               var web = ctx.get_web();
               var page = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(window.location.pathname);

                 var listItem = page.get_listItemAllFields();
 //We can set any value to any of the property by the below lines.
                 //listItem.set_item('PublishingPageContent', '{Updated with ECMA}');
                 listItem.update();

               page.checkIn();
               page.publish();
               ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, checkIn_Success),Function.createDelegate(this, checkIn_fail));
           }
 </script>
```

To checkout

```
 function CheckOutFile() {
             var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();            
                 var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
                 this.list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle("Shared Documents");
                 this.item = list.getItemById(1);
                 this.file = this.item.get_file();
                 this.file.checkOut();
                 clientContext.load(this.file)
                 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));            
         }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not clear for me how should I pass the details (list name, item ID) to the function

Comment: SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(); this function will give you selected list items from the OOTB list. You can get the list guid as well from the Selection method